# return pointer from C++ function to C function

Tags: c++, c

I'm still beginner for C and C++ programming. I'm currently developing a code to call a function in C++ from C. This is due to my main code is written in C and I need to use certain library which written in C++. I'm using Eigen library for this approach. I'm currently have a problem to return the value which produced in C++ to C. I would like to return (A) from *.cpp to *.c and preview the result (printf) in *.c.

Here are my sample codes.

1. Main code in main.c

   ```
   #include "lib2run.h"
   #include "stdio.h"

   int main () 
   {
       struct C_MatrixXd *matrix1;
       matrix1 = play_matrix ();
       printf("Here is matrix1:\n");
       MatrixXd_print(matrix1);  // <-- I want to use printf to print matrix1, not like this
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Header file lib2run.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    struct C_MatrixXd* play_matrix ();
    void MatrixXd_print (const struct C_MatrixXd *m);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // end extern "C"
#endif
```

3. Here is the code in lib2run.cpp

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <Eigenvalues>
   #include <Core>
   #include "lib2run.h"

   using namespace Eigen;
   using Eigen::MatrixXd;
   using Eigen::EigenSolver;

   inline C_MatrixXd* eigen_to_c(MatrixXd& ref)
   {
         return reinterpret_cast<C_MatrixXd*>(&ref);
   }

   inline MatrixXd& c_to_eigen(C_MatrixXd* ptr)
   {
         return *reinterpret_cast<MatrixXd*>(ptr);
   }

   inline const MatrixXd& c_to_eigen(const C_MatrixXd* ptr)
   {
         return *reinterpret_cast<const MatrixXd*>(ptr);
   }

   C_MatrixXd* play_matrix ()
   {
         MatrixXd A = MatrixXd::Random(3,3);
         std::cout << "Here is a random 3x3 matrix, A:" << std::endl << A << std::endl << std::endl;
         EigenSolver<MatrixXd> es(A);
         MatrixXd D = es.pseudoEigenvalueMatrix();
         MatrixXd V = es.pseudoEigenvectors();
         std::cout << "The pseudo-eigenvalue matrix D is:" << std::endl << D << std::endl<< std::endl;
         std::cout << "The pseudo-eigenvector matrix V is:" << std::endl << V << std::endl<< std::endl;
         std::cout << "Finally, V * D * V^(-1) = " << std::endl << V * D * V.inverse() << std::endl<< std::endl;

         return eigen_to_c (A);
    }

    void MatrixXd_print(const C_MatrixXd *m)
    {
         std::cout << c_to_eigen(m) << std::endl;
    }
   ```

Comment: It would be far easier to just convert your C code to C++.

Comment: You cannot “use `printf` to print a matrix” like this.  What you *can* do is (in the C++ part) call the `.data()` member of the matrix to obtain a pointer to the contiguous array holding the data, pass it to the C code and then loop over it, `printf()`ing every value.  I don't think you'll do yourself a favor with this.  Eigen was really designed as a C++ library.  If you are mostly coding in C, you should probably use the traditional BLAS / LAPACK interface instead (or port all your code to C++ as @NeilKirk said).

Comment: Does MatrixXd define << operator? If not MatrixXd_print won't work. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Does this work? It looks like a pointer to an automatic variable is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ live happily together. The problem is what @jxh pointed out. You are returning a pointer to an object that will not exist when the point is used. In your case, and to modify your code as little as possible, you should use `new` to allocate MatrixA.

```
// Allocate a new matrix which will live beyond this function
MatrixXd* A = new MatrixXd(3,3);
// Copy a random matrix to it
*A = MatrixXd::Random(3,3);
// ...
return A;
```

If you can I would also change your `main.c` to `main.cpp` and compile with a C++ compiler (like g++), then scrap your C_MatrixXd.